# How can I make rover wheels touching the ground easier to animate?

Tags: animation

I have a rover with wheels attached to axles that rotate along the Y axis. I want the rover to move forward (x) with all 8 wheels on the ground at all times, except I don't want to spend the time rotating the axles every frame. Is there an easier way to animate this?

[image]

Comment: Are the wheels on the left side linked to the ones on the right?
I'm guessing some system with IKs is the answer.

Comment: @Firewill No, they're not linked. I'll go ahead and try IK's